# How can I avoid unhandled exception from my code?

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

My code is:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
 for (int index = 1; index < pagename.Length; index++) {
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
     statsRequest = statsRequest.Replace(pagename[index - 1], pagename[index]);
     statsRequest = statsRequest.Replace(title[index - 1], title[index]);
```

Every time I run the program, it works properly until it reaches this point, then I get an "index out of range" exception.

Why do I get that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is `title.Length`?

Comment: title.length is the length of the title page name

Comment: If `title.Length` < `pagename.Length` you will get an exception when `index` >= `title.Length`

Comment: I have checked the title.length and everything is ok it shouldn't make an error

Comment: Note that it was working properly before and now the error is displayed i dont know why

Comment: Use the debugger to find which line causes the exception. If `pagename.Length` is < 1 it will fail on the `for` line.

Comment: Dear Peter I used the debugger as you said and the debugger shows that the eroor is in this line                                                                                      statsRequest = statsRequest.Replace(title[index - 1], title[index]);